# Gradle NoclassDefFoundError on ubuntu

Tags: android, gradle, java, linphone, linphone-sdk

I'm trying to build linphone in ubuntu 64 bit machine.

i have generated the make file and when i initiate make command on it,

The following error occurs :

```
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.
     > java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext
```

why is this error occuring? im using openjdk-8-jre

Here is the full error

```
Reading makefiles...
```

Updating goal targets....
 File 'all' does not exist.
   File 'generate-apk' does not exist.
     File 'java-clean' does not exist.
    Must remake target 'java-clean'.
./gradlew clean
NOTE: Picked up the following options via JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:
  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'linphone-android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.
  >   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.
  >   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.267 secs
Makefile:17: recipe for target 'java-clean' failed
make: *** [java-clean] Error 1

Comment: Run again with giving `-s` to Gradle to get the full stacktrace of the error.

Comment: im building this project

https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android

ive executed prepare.py and then when i execute make command,the following error occurs.

Comment: So? As I said, either edit `prepare.py` or directly the generated makefile so that the problematic Gradle call is additionally given the `-s` flag.

Comment: Please file a bug in Ubuntu against OpenJDK. It sounds like their OpenJDK package (that provides `sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext`) is broken.